# Windows 10 online roaming profile

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 is making first steps in storing files and some settings onto OneDrive.

I would like to know if its possible and how. To store or sync **ALL** I am not talking a document or email account setting, but everything in windows themes file extension the works. After a reinstallation of windows or login on different PC/laptop I like to get the exact same environment hassle-free.

I do get quite far with cloudstorage and Portable apps but its a constant setup and change.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "hassle free". For any solution right now you'd need to have additional steps to retrieve the backed up data and restore it to its correct location because OneDrive doesn't do this all by default yet

Comment: Unfortunately, OneDrive currently cannot be functioned as roaming profile or backup system image. One Drive is only a free Online storage that comes with your Microsoft account where you can save your documents, photos, videos, music files , etc. and can access your data from any device using the Microsoft Account.